# Unexpected token s in JSON at position 1813

Tags: angular

Please help in resolving

> Unexpected token s in JSON at position 1813

My code looks like this:

```
GetAllAnalysisStatuses(): void {   
   this.http.get('http://localhost:9090/analytics/analysisStatuses')
    .subscribe(result => { console.log(result); 
     this.AnalysisStatuses = result.json().data;
    });
}
```

My JSON looks like this:

```
[ { "analysisId": 1, "analysisName": "01 consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et ", "analysisTypeName": "Lorem ipmod tempor ", "analysisStatus": "CREATED", "comments": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua", "pirorityIncreasable": true, "isFavourite": true, "scenariosStatus": [] } ]
```

I have tried:

```
public GetAllAnalysisStatuses = (): Observable<any> => { 
    console.log("(TS File) :CommonService.ts >>> (Method): GetAllAnalysisStatuses >");
    return this._http.get(this.actionUrl + 'analysisStatuses' ) 
      .map((response) => { console.log("GetAllAnalysisStatuses", response); 
      var result: ServerResponse = response.json(); 
      return result; })
      .catch(this.handleError); }
```

Comment: "[
  {
    "analysisId": 1,
    "analysisName": "01  consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et ",
    "analysisTypeName": "Lorem ipmod tempor ",
    "analysisStatus": "CREATED",
    "comments": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua",
    "pirorityIncreasable": true,
    "isFavourite": true,
    "scenariosStatus": []
  }
  
]"

Comment: Please, when asked to provide code, please edit your question and add the code, this time I did it for you. But as a tip for the future!

Answer (score 0):

You should change `result.json().data` to:

`result.json()`

Your json suggest that there is no `data` object in you json, but an array, which I assume you want to populate to `AnalysisStatuses`.

Usually though we use `map` to map the data first in a service which makes the http-call, so you can try:

```
GetAllAnalysisStatuses(): void {   
   this.http.get('http://localhost:9090/analytics/analysisStatuses')
     .map(res => res.json())
     .subscribe(result => { 
        console.log(result); 
        this.AnalysisStatuses = result;
    });
}
```

EDIT: Looking at your comment about your code, I did not fully understand what's going on with that code. Please take a look at **[HTTP-tutorial](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/tutorial/toh-pt6.html)** of how to do http-calls! I recommend all the tutorials there, they are really good!

Moreover, when you have that problem handled...

Use the safe navigation operator in view `{{AnalysisStatus?.id}}"` or `*ngIf="AnalysisStatuses"`, since this is an asynchronous, the safe navigation operator or `*ngIf` ensures that app won't throw an error, since view is (usually) rendered before data has arrived.

More about safe-navigation operator **[here](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/template-syntax.html#!#safe-navigation-operator)** and a working **[plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/hYhBnUfh2ZS0HuqqODvv)** of your code. Feeling super nice today and provided with a working sample ;)

A sidenote... Instead of doing the http-call in the component, I suggest you have a service which handles that and then do the subscribing in the component.

Comment: Hmmh. And your data is fine in the console log, meaning the output is just like you posted in comment? By the way, please add any additional info in your question instead of comment :) Have you tried mapping the data?

Comment: Is this function in a service or component? Usually we have the mapping in a service which makes the http-calls, and in the component we subscribe to the response. Please share more code.

Comment: Still i am facing the issue can you check JSON once whether format is correct

Comment: Unexpected token s in JSON at position 1817

Comment: You JSON is fine. Tested it, works fine! You would have to share some more code.

Comment: How are you trying to access your data in your view? Do you have a separate service?

Comment: can you connect my machine

Comment: No I cannot. Please provide requested code in question, or even better, recreate the issue in a plunker :)

Comment: public GetAllAnalysisStatuses = (): Observable<any> => {
    console.log("(TS File) :CommonService.ts >>> (Method): GetAllAnalysisStatuses >");
    return this._http.get(this.actionUrl + 'analysisStatuses' )
    .map((response) => {
      console.log("GetAllAnalysisStatuses",response);
            var result: ServerResponse = response.json();  
       
      return result;
    }).catch(this.handleError);
  }

Comment: Error is while converting into response.json();

Comment: i am using sandbox api

Comment: Please share this object ServerResponse